Initial values not coming in edit page
I have an edit page. I pass the id through the URL which queries the data from the db. The data should be displayed in the input components. Its not displaying but when I refresh the page it works.
I returned error if there was an error. Inside the component which I have done now and outside the component. Both don't work


//react imports
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

// material-ui
import {
  Button,
  FormHelperText,
  Grid,
  InputLabel,
  OutlinedInput,
  Stack,
  CircularProgress,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  LinearProgress,
} from "@mui/material";

// third party
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Formik, FieldArray } from "formik";
import axios from "axios";
import { useQueries } from "@tanstack/react-query";

// project import
import AnimateButton from "components/@extended/AnimateButton";
import { base_url } from "utils/baseurl";
import { fetchData } from "utils/fetchData";
import Error from "utils/Error";
import { useNavigate } from "../../../node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index";
import Progress from "utils/Progress";
// ============================|| CLASS - EDIT FORM ||============================ //

const ClassEdit = () => {
  const classId = useParams().id;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [classResult, teacherResult] = useQueries({
    queries: [
      {
        queryKey: ["classData"],
        queryFn: async () => {
          try {
            const data = await fetchData(`class/${classId}`);
            return data;
          } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`Failed to fetch class data: ${error.message}`);
          }
        },
      },
      {
        queryKey: ["teacherData"],
        queryFn: async () => {
          try {
            const data = await fetchData("teacher/get-all");
            return data;
          } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`Failed to fetch class data: ${error.message}`);
          }
        },
      },
    ],
  });
  const { data: classData, error: classError, isPending: classIsPending } = classResult;
  const { data: teacherData, error: teacherError, isPending: teacherIsPending } = teacherResult;

  return (
    <>
      {classError && <Error severity="error">There was an unexpected error</Error>}
      {classIsPending ? (
        <Progress />
      ) : (
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            className: classData.className,
            division: classData.division,
            batch: classData.batch,
            fees: classData.fees,
            subjects: classData.subjects,
            teacherId: classData.teacherId || "",
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            className: Yup.number(),
            division: Yup.string().max(255),
            batch: Yup.number(),
            teacherId: Yup.string(),
            fees: Yup.number(),
            subjects: Yup.array(),
          })}
          onSubmit={async (values, { setErrors, setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {
            try {
              const response = await axios.put(`${base_url}/class/${classId}`, values);
              if (!response.data.success) setErrors({ submit: response.data.message });
              else navigate(`/class`);

              setStatus({ success: false });
              setSubmitting(false);
            } catch (err) {
              console.error(err);
              setStatus({ success: false });
              setErrors({ submit: err.message });
              setSubmitting(false);
            }
          }}
        >
          {({ errors, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, touched, values }) => (
            <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                  <Stack spacing={1}>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="class-name">Class Standard</InputLabel>
                    <OutlinedInput
                      fullWidth
                      id="class-name"
                      ذ
                      value={values.className}
                      name="className"
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      error={Boolean(touched.className && errors.className)}
                    />
                    {touched.className && errors.className && (
                      <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-className-signup">
                        {errors.className}
                      </FormHelperText>
                    )}
                  </Stack>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                  <Stack spacing={1}>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="division">Division</InputLabel>
                    <OutlinedInput
                      fullWidth
                      error={Boolean(touched.division && errors.division)}
                      id="division"
                      value={values.division}
                      name="division"
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    {touched.division && errors.division && (
                      <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-division-signup">
                        {errors.division}
                      </FormHelperText>
                    )}
                  </Stack>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Stack spacing={1}>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="teacherId">Teacher</InputLabel>
                    <Select
                      fullWidth
                      id="teacherId"
                      value={values.teacherId}
                      name="teacherId"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      error={touched.teacherId && errors.teacherId}
                    >
                      {teacherError && <MenuItem key="error">Cannot find teacher data</MenuItem>}
                      {teacherIsPending ? (
                        <LinearProgress />
                      ) : (
                        teacherData.map((teacher) => (
                          <MenuItem key={teacher._id} value={teacher._id}>
                            {teacher.name}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))
                      )}
                    </Select>
                    {touched.teacherId && errors.teacherId && (
                      <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-teacherId-signup">
                        {errors.teacherId}
                      </FormHelperText>
                    )}
                  </Stack>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Stack spacing={1}>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="batch">Batch Start</InputLabel>
                    <OutlinedInput
                      fullWidth
                      error={Boolean(touched.batch && errors.batch)}
                      id="batch"
                      value={values.batch}
                      name="batch"
                      type="number"
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      placeholder="2019"
                      inputProps={{}}
                    />
                    {touched.batch && errors.batch && (
                      <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-batch-signup">
                        {errors.batch}
                      </FormHelperText>
                    )}
                  </Stack>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Stack spacing={1}>
                    <InputLabel htmlFor="fees">Fees</InputLabel>
                    <OutlinedInput
                      fullWidth
                      error={Boolean(touched.fees && errors.fees)}
                      id="fees"
                      value={values.fees}
                      name="fees"
                      type="number"
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      inputProps={{}}
                    />
                    {touched.fees && errors.fees && (
                      <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-fees-signup">
                        {errors.fees}
                      </FormHelperText>
                    )}
                  </Stack>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <Stack spacing={1} sx={{ mt: "8px" }}>
                    <FieldArray
                      name="subjects"
                      render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                        <div>
                          {values.subjects &&
                            values.subjects.map((subject, index) => (
                              <div key={index}>
                                <InputLabel htmlFor={`subjects.${index}`}>Subject</InputLabel>
                                <OutlinedInput
                                  fullWidth
                                  id={`subjects.${index}`}
                                  value={values.subjects[index]}
                                  name={`subjects.${index}`}
                                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                                  onChange={handleChange}
                                  // error={
                                  //   touched.subjects[index] &&
                                  //   errors.subjects[index] &&
                                  //   Boolean(
                                  //     touched.subjects[index] &&
                                  //       errors.subjects[index]
                                  //   )
                                  // }
                                />
                                {/* {touched.subjects[index] &&
                                errors.subjects[index] && (
                                  <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-phone-signup">
                                    {errors.subjects[index]}
                                  </FormHelperText>
                                )} */}
                                <Button type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}>
                                  Remove
                                </Button>
                              </div>
                            ))}
                          <Button type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push("")}>
                            Add
                          </Button>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    />
                  </Stack>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <AnimateButton>
                    <Button
                      disableElevation
                      disabled={isSubmitting}
                      size="large"
                      type="submit"
                      variant="contained"
                      color="primary"
                    >
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                  </AnimateButton>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ClassEdit;
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>




What actions leads to the component being load? Is it a route change?
Also I would add enabled: !!classId to classData query. The query key should be ['classData', classId] as well.

It's a route change.. Thank you for your suggestions..since the component only loads when the route change, and the route always will have classId, is it necessary for enabled

Any idea on how to fix this bug?

One reason I can think of right now is because on your previous page you also use classData as a query key but storing other shape of data. Thus when you query with the same key its gonna return the cached value. This can also explain why the refresh works because React query is now a clean state.
Try changing your query key to [classData', classId] and it should solve that issue.
